# Can I combine position: sticky and float: left?

Tags: css

I have some legacy code in which float: left is used on every element. So the question is can I use position sticky along with float: left?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav></nav>
    <search-filter class="search-sticky"><search-filter>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper, main, footer, header{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
}
.search-sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 117px; // height of header
}
```

I want to stick element to the top of the page still using float: left.

Comment: why float left if it is 100% width? it makes no sense to have it. Also in the day of css3, you shouldn't need to use float on anything apart from what it is meant to be used for - images within text

Comment: Hi @Veselin Kontić , If you want to stick the element on top then why you can use the attribute top:117px; instead of that you can use top:0; and position:fixed.

Comment: @Pete I already told you, this is legacy code and this is not real example. I want to know is it possible to use float: left and position: sticky in general, not to finish my work.

Comment: @Sandeep This search-filter was fixed before, I just want to know can sticky and float work together.

Comment: Just because it's legacy doesn't mean you cannot change it - still makes no sense to have float with 100%.  Anyway, why not just try it and see what happens rather than asking a question.  If it doesn't work as you would expect, then ask a question how to fix it

Comment: _“I want to stick element to the top of the page still using float: left.”_ - meaning, you just want to be able to leave the float in your stylesheet - or that you actually want it to have an _effect_ on how the element is displayed? I guess the latter won’t really be possible, because what CSS 2.1 specified in https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo should most likely still apply for sticky as well, and the means the computed value of float becomes none.

Comment: Hi @Veselin Kontić , Either you write both code together it will work but their is no need to write float:left; that is unnecessary. Try to create a design with min code whether it is CSS or any other language. It will improve your compile time as well.

Comment: Hi @Veselin Kontić, if you write width:100% that means you already occupy whole space of browser and you wrote that you want to fix at top means you know the position as well , When we want to fluid layout at that time we can write float element. But you want at the top so no need to apply CSS which used for fluid type of layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if so, you must add the nav to the float as well.

```
.wrapper, main, footer, nav{
  float:left;
}
```

If this is not the desired solution, please provide a more detailed description of the problem and what your goal is.